# is there a way to get a text file of the cmd prompt? that is, all the data that printf shows in codeblocks c?

Tags: c, cmd, printf, codeblocks

I'm currently writing a bunch of calculations in c using codeblocks and printing them off to the cmd prompt using the printf(); function. I am trying to create a graph from the data gathered. Is there a ways to get a hard copy or a text/doc file of all the data I printed out or better yet, is there a way to get all the values on the cmd prompt into a graph?

Comment: run the program from command prompt and put `>foo.txt` on the end of the commandline.  Or change your program to use `fprintf` instead of `printf`.  Or copy-paste from the output window

Comment: I always find MS Excel to be the easiest way to create a graph.  If you don't have Access to Excel (sorry pun intended :P), check out LibreOffice or OpenOffice.   There are **many** free alternatives if that doesn't suite your needs:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_information_graphics_software

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just save them to a file?

Great example of writing to a file:

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
if (f == NULL)
{
   printf("Error opening file!\n");
   exit(1);
}

 /* print some text */
 const char *text = "Write this to the file";
 fprintf(f, "Some text: %s\n", text);

/* print integers and floats */
int i = 1;
float py = 3.1415927;
fprintf(f, "Integer: %d, float: %f\n", i, py);

/* printing single chatacters */
char c = 'A';
fprintf(f, "A character: %c\n", c);

fclose(f);
```

Another solution is just pipeing the output using `> file.txt`